# Getting Openlayer Vector features vs clusters

Tags: openlayers

I am using openLayers Vector with a cluster strategy. When I use Vector.features to get the features returned as a list, it returns an array of clusters and not the array of features. This makes the features unable to be addressed individually. Does anyone know how can I get the features list while using the clustering strategy? Any help is appreciated.
(Eg. If there are 5 features in my KML which are clustered as 1, then I get vector.features.length=1. I need the original features list which will have a length of 5)

Below is the implementation of my Vector:

```
var maps_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()],
                     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "kml/maps.kml",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                           extractStyles: true, 
                           extractAttributes: true,
                        })
                    })
                 })

 var my_array = maps_layer.features; //Here is the problem.
```

Here is the documentation: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html

Answer (score 1):

You* can give this a try, I haven't got the environment to test it right now but it should work. (Caution: You* refers to search engine users ..)

```
function getFeatures(maps_layer) {
    var features = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < maps_layer.features.length; i++) {
        if (maps_layer.features[i].cluster) {
            for (var j = 0; j < maps_layer.features[i].cluster.length; j++)
            features.push(maps_layer.features[i].cluster[j]);
        } else {
            features.push(maps_layer.features[i]);
        }

    }
}
```